# Robot Framework - Database library how to connect using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql, database, robotframework, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL server database using windows authentication, i Have tried the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup  Connect To Database Using Custom Params   pyodbc    ${DBHost_ConnectionString}

Suite Teardown    Disconnect From Database
```

Connection string :

```
${DBHost_ConnectionString}=        Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

Which produces

```
pyodbc.connect(db_api_2.connect(Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=yes;))
```

This is the Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use semicolon (`;`) as delimiters, use commas (`,`):

```
${DBHost_ConnectionString}=  Set Variable    Server='ServerName', Database='DbName', Trusted_Connection='yes'
```

Also don't forget to put the arguments values in quotes.

---

The reason is the string you provide [turns up as-is in the connect() method](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/blob/master/src/DatabaseLibrary/connection_manager.py#L147) - so they must follow the proper python syntax for method's arguments.